# Nested Gridview htmlException was unhandled

Tags: asp.net

I've been battling this nested collapsible data grid view feature in my application. I have finally got the grids nested  and the connection strings working properly, but now when I try to View the collapsible information under the first gridview I receive this error. I Figured attaching a screenshot with the code could help because its such a general exception error.

FYI: in my select statement, I do not receive this error when I put in my ISBN data field (PK for textBooks Table) but after thinking about it, it doesn't make any sense because CourseID is my PK in my Course Table and my FK in my textBooks table so if I'm not mistaken that would mean for the nested grid view, I would be selecting all from textbooks where the CourseID of gridview1 = DataKeys..... and my DataKey in my aspx page is CourseID.

[image]

I need to be able to click the "plus" icon, drop down and view all the books that correspond to the CourseID but in this case I click it and nothing is to show.

[image]

Comment: Is there a column named "thirteenISBN" in textBooks?

Comment: Yes that is my PK in table textBooks followed by my FK of CourseID

Comment: Is it thriteen or thirteen in the table? Note the spelling difference.

Comment: its thirteenISBN but If i place that in place of CourseID in this case, I do not receive the error but I cannot pull the book related to the course. I'll attached a SS of what I'm trying to accomplish

Comment: Do you have a field in your GridView that is trying to bind to "thriteenISBN" instead of "thirteenISBN". I can't see the markup for the GridView. The error indicates something is looking for the field "thriteenISBN" vs "thirteenISBN".